# Float after dynamic height

Tags: css, css-float

I have a JQuery image fader with width: 100%; and height: auto;

This is awesome, because it also works on the IPhone.

Now I want content to "float" after my JQuery slider, but I'm really having issues with that, since I use height auto, to get the right proportions, with the 100% wide image.

I've tried: overflow: hidden, auto and clear: both; width: 100% on the following element, also I've tried floating both elements, but it won't work without a defined height. If I define a height, It works.. but, I want the height to be dynamically..

Can this be done, with CSS, or do I need to use JS?

Here is the site: www.magento-design.dk (Its a Joomla, with foundation). And I want the foundation demo content, to float after the JQuery slider.

Answer (score 0):

What I'd suggest is setting the height to a certain value and then changing it through JavaScript when the content inside changes.  A CSS height of auto doesn't have a set pixel value, so you need to define one through JavaScript.

Set up your height changing as a function in JavaScript which you can call on $(document).ready() as well as on your content change call.

**Edit 1:**

I would use the following code to achieve what you're looking to do...

```
jQuery(document).ready({
    set_img_height();
});

jQuery("#contentDIV").load("data.html", function() {
    set_img_height();
});

function set_img_height() {
    var height = jQuery('#slideshow').height();
    jQuery('.imagefade').css('height', height);
}
```

Of course, it's a little hard for me to write this without knowing more specifically what you're looking for.  But the basic idea is as follows:

1. You create a function which will get the height of your slideshow and make that the height of all elements with a class of "imagefade"
2. Next you call this function in the document ready function (when the PHP is processed and when the HTML is completely loaded)
3. Lastly, call this function again with the loading of information using a callback function.  I don't know how you're loading content, but I basically assumed you're loading a file "data.html" into a div with an id of "contentDIV", after that finishes... it calls the set_img_height function defined below it.

This code likely isn't copy and paste material for you, but based off of you not providing any actual code yourself, this is the best I can do.  Hopefully this will at least point you in the right direction!

Comment: Okay thanks,
So I wrote this, and it works, however I would like it to update real time:

 var img = document.getElementById('slideshow'); 
  var height = img.clientHeight;

  function set_img_height()
  {
  jQuery('.imagefade').css('height',height);
  }
  jQuery(document).ready(set_img_height()) 

Annoying, the float, not just working on height: auto.. would be so much easier...

Comment: I just edited my post to reflect what you're needing.  Hopefully it helps point you in the right direction if it doesn't solve your problem.